# How to set signature if use np.array as an input in numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I wanna set signature for my numba function to regulate its type. However, after doing so, I find that the function didn't work. How should I set the signature.

```
mat = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(1000000, 10))

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def f(mat):
    max_min = 0
    for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
        max_min += mat[i].max() - mat[i].min()
    return max_min / mat.shape[0]

start = time.time()
print(f(mat))
end = time.time()
end - start
```

if I do this way, it works fine.

But if I do this way:

```
@nb.jit(nb.float64(nb.float64), nopython=True)
def f(mat):
    max_min = 0
    for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
        max_min += mat[i].max() - mat[i].min()
    return max_min / mat.shape[0]

start = time.time()
print(f(mat))
end = time.time()
end - start
```

it reports an error:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'shape' of type float64
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

```py
@nb.jit(nb.float64(nb.types.Array(nb.float64, 2, "C")), nopython=True)
def f(mat):
    max_min = 0
    for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
        max_min += mat[i].max() - mat[i].min()
    return max_min / mat.shape[0]
```

I.e., the [`nb.types.Array(nb.float64, 2, "C")`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html#id1) tells it that the input should be 2 dimensional array of `float64` values, with a C-style memory layout.

Comment: I SEE. I really wanna know where can I get the information about every signature that applies to numba. Like I can't find nb.types.Array in the document.

Comment: I think everything should be listed here https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html, with the Array type described in the "Advanced types" section.